# Y&Y TeX versus TeX Live/MikTeX

Tags: miktex, texlive

I noticed that the formerly commercial Y&Y TeX is available under http://tug.org/yandy/. My question is: compared with a modern MikTeX or TeX Live is there any feature in Y&Y TeX that could be interesting?

Comment: It has no `pdftex`, no e-TeX, no XeTeX, no LuaTeX. It possibly has a good DVI previewer. Surely I'm not going to buy Windows in order to test it. `;-)`

Comment: You can use _any_ type 1 font. However, that's nowadays not really a sensation ...

Comment: From the link you shown: ... Y&Y, Inc. **closed in 2004** ... Are you really not afraid of the dead? ;-)

Comment: TeX was "closed" in the 80s of last century ...

Comment: Well the own page of Y&Y says it's closed but if there are volunteers for update it maybe it can be functional yet. But if it could be interesting is very subjective, for some people could be, for other not. Perhaps you could find it interesting, you could try.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can see, development of Y&Y TeX stopped more than a decade ago. The suite doesn't provide any of the recent additions to TeX: there's no `pdftex`, no e-TeX support, no XeTeX, no LuaTeX.

Maybe the DVI driver to Postscript is better than `dvips`, but who needs it nowadays?